# Compiler Error prevents me from Adding Product into Database Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello im building a Webshop website and when i press the Submit button to add a new product to the database gives this  error, how to change the code so that it doesn't give this error.

#### Here is the Code from ManageProducts.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Webshop3.Models;

namespace Webshop3.Pages.Management
{
    public partial class ManageProducts : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetImages();

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                    FillPage(id);
                }


            }


        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            Product product = CreateProduct();

            //testojme nese url ka parameter id
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {

                // ID existon -> update rreshtin ekzistes
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                lblResult.Text = productModel.UpdateProduct(id, product);
            }

            else
            {
                // nese nuk ekziston ID , krijo rresht te ri
                lblResult.Text = productModel.InsertProduct(product);

            }






        }

        private void FillPage(int id)
        {
            //Marim produktin e selektuar nga databaza
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            var product = productModel.GetProduct(id);


            //Mbushim textboxat
            txtDescription.Text = product.Description;
            txtName.Text = product.Name;
            txtPrice.Text = product.Price.ToString();


            ddlImage.SelectedValue = product.Image;
            ddlType.SelectedValue = product.TypeId.ToString();




        }

        private void GetImages()
        {
            try
            {
                // Marim Images te Dropdown
                string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));

                // Vendoj FileName ne arraylist

                ArrayList imageList = new ArrayList();
                foreach (string image in images)
                {
                    string imageName = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                    imageList.Add(imageName);
                }

                ddlImage.DataSource = imageList;
                ddlImage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlImage.DataBind();

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lblResult.Text = e.ToString();
            }

        }

        private Product CreateProduct()
        {
            var product = new Product();
            product.Name = txtName.Text;
            product.Price = int.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
            product.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
            product.Description = txtDescription.Text;

            product.Image = ddlImage.SelectedValue;

            return product;

        }


    }
}
```

Here is the Code of Product.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Webshop.Models;
using Webshop3.Models;

namespace Webshop3.Pages
{
    public partial class Product : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int Price { get;  set; }
        public string Name { get;  set; }
        public string Description { get;  set; }
        public string Image { get;  set; }
        public int TypeId { get; internal set; }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillPage();
        }

        private void FillPage()
        {
            // marim te dhenat e produktit te selektuar
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
                var product = productModel.GetProduct(id);

                // Mbushet faqja me data
                lblPrice.Text = "Price per unit: <br/>$" + product.Price;
                lblTitle.Text = product.Name;
                lblDescription.Text = product.Description;
                lblItemNr.Text = id.ToString();
                imgProduct.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;

                // Mbushe dropdownList me numrat 1-20
                int[] amount = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
                ddlAmount.DataSource = amount;
                ddlAmount.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlAmount.DataBind();
            }

        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                int clientId = -1;
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                int amount = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAmount.SelectedValue);

                Cart cart = new Cart
                {
                    Amount = amount,
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    DatePurchased = DateTime.Now,
                    IsInCart = true,
                    ProductID = id
                };
                CartModel model = new CartModel();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### Here is the Compiler Error

[image: Compiler Error]

#### Here is the ProductModel Class Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Webshop3.Pages;

namespace Webshop3.Models
{
    public class ProductModel
    {
        public string InsertProduct(Product product)
        {
            try
            {

                webshop2Entities1 db = new webshop2Entities1();
                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return product.Name + "was succesfully inserted";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Error:" + e;
            }

        }

        public string UpdateProduct(int id, Product product)
        {


            try
            {
                webshop2Entities1 db = new webshop2Entities1();

                // Merret objekti nga db
                Product p = db.Products.Find(id);
                p.Name = product.Name;
                p.Price = product.Price;
                p.TypeId = product.TypeId;
                p.Description = product.Description;
                p.Image = product.Image;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return product.Name + "was succesfully updated";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return "Error:" + e;


            }





        }

        internal string UpdateProduct(int id, Pages.Product product)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }



        public string DeleteProduct(int id)
        {
            try
            {

                webshop2Entities1 db = new webshop2Entities1();
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);

                db.Products.Attach(product);
                db.Products.Remove(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return product.Name + "was succesfully deleted";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Error:" + e;

            }








        }
        public Product GetProduct(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (webshop2Entities1 db = new webshop2Entities1())
                {
                    Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
                    return product;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;

            }

        }

        public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            try
            {
                using (webshop2Entities1 db = new webshop2Entities1())
                {
                    List<Product> products = (from x in db.Products
                                              select x).ToList();
                    return products;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return null;
            }



        }

        public List<Product> GetProductsByType(int typeId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (webshop2Entities1 db = new webshop2Entities1())
                {
                    List<Product> products = (from x in db.Products
                                              where x.TypeId == typeId
                                              select x).ToList();
                    return products;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return null;
            }


        }


    }




}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because all information is provided in error. It is clear how to solve this error if you can read error.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the name of your classes. You have your entity framework model named "Product", while also having a aspx.cs page called Product. Even though they have the same name, they are different classes, one in the namespace Webshop3.Pages.Product and the other on Webshop3.Product. The compiler error is that you are passing a Webshop3.Pages.Product to a method that is expecting the other type, Webshop3.Product.

One of the methods you are using are expecting the wrong type, or you are passing the wrong type. Find out wich product type is the correct one, and hover your cursor on all the references to find out where the type error is

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. In your `ProductModel` file you are referencing the namespace `Webshop3.Pages`, so the `Product` type being referenced is `Webshop3.Pages.Product`. However, your `ProductModel` class methods are expecting the type `Webshop3.Product`.

Fix the `using` to reference the correct namespace, and that should fix the issue.

Comment: Can you write the Code and the change i need to make